# How to analyze this opamp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, kirchhoffs-laws, non-inverting

So with the following circuit (currently studying for an exam):

I am able to get V- just through the voltage divider composed of 2R and R at the non inverting terminal. However, once there, I am unsure of how to get Vout just because of the 3R resistor going from Vout and ground. Can I treat the feedback loop resistor, R2, and the 3R resistor, as a voltage divider that gives me Vout in terms of V-? If so, then what about the current that exits the opamp?

[image]

Comment: What are you assuming about the output impedance or resistance of the op amp?

Comment: Zero output impedance. Is it even possible to study this circuit in that condition?

Comment: Sure. But think about what "zero output impedance" means. Is there any limit to the current available from the op amp output? Does the output voltage change if you increase the load on the output?

Comment: Why do you think R3 is a part of any voltage divider in the circuit? What would it divide? Ask yourself how it could even have an effect of V+ or V-, assuming the op-amp is ideal and R3 is larger that 0 ohms.

Comment: You mention "V-" in the text but there is no "V-" in the circuit. Do you know how an ideal opamp behaves? What does it do? What determines the output voltage/current of the opamp? So what does that mean if R3 is present or not?

Comment: Maybe 3R was intentionally put up just to fool you?  If you think so, do not succumb to the "provocation" - :)

Comment: I know how to analyze this circuit without 3R -- V- refers to the voltage at the inverting terminal. I think, having 3R might actually not change anything?

Comment: And why do you think so? It is not enough to just answer yes or no;  you must also be able to defend your answer.

Comment: BTW can you answer how many voltage dividers there are in the circuit? And how much would they be if the op-amp had some output resistance?

Comment: I'm not sure how to defend my answer. But I see one voltage divider after Vin, at the non inverting input. If the opamp had output resistance, I think this is where there would be an additional one?

Comment: And what do the two 2R resistors do?

Comment: Think. If you change the value from 3R to something else, what happens to Vout?

Comment: Vout doesn't change when I change 3R right?

Comment: To answer that: does the voltage of any other node change or depend upon the value of the 3R resistor?

Comment: I don't believe so

Answer (score 3):

Premises about the op. amp.:

- zero input current
- infinite gain (V+ = V-)
- zero output resistance
- no input/output voltage restrictions

First part is a simple voltage divider:

[image]

$$V_+ = V_{in}\frac{R}{3R} = \frac{V_{in}}{3}$$

The other is a also a voltage divider with equal resistors:

[image]

$$ V_- = \frac{V_{out}}{2}$$

Since V+ = V-:

$$ V_{out} = \frac{2 V_{in}}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEqWSZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2\\
\\
0=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_2\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_x-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_x-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = Vx;
V2 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2, 0 == I3 + I4, I5 == I4 + I6, 
   I1 + I6 == I2 + I3 + I5, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == V2/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == V3/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, Vx, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/(R1 + R2), I2 -> Vi/(R1 + R2), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3), I4 -> -((R2 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3)), 
  I5 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R5), 
  I6 -> (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R5), 
  Vx -> (R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2), V3 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

Now, using \$\text{R}_x:=\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4\$, \$\text{R}_1=2\text{R}\$ and \$\text{R}_2=\text{R}\$ we can simplify the transfer function as follows:

$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{\text{R}\left(\text{R}_x+\text{R}_x\right)}{\text{R}_x\left(2\text{R}+\text{R}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}\left(2\text{R}_x\right)}{\text{R}_x\left(3\text{R}\right)}=\frac{2\text{R}\text{R}_x}{3\text{R}\text{R}_x}=\frac{2}{3}\tag7$$

Running the code again with your resistor values, we get:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = Vx;
V2 = Vx;
R1 = 2 R;
R2 = R;
R3 = Rx;
R4 = Rx;
R5 = 3 R;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2, 0 == I3 + I4, I5 == I4 + I6, 
   I1 + I6 == I2 + I3 + I5, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == V2/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == V3/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, Vx, V3}]]

Out[2]={{I1 -> Vi/(3 R), I2 -> Vi/(3 R), I3 -> Vi/(3 Rx), I4 -> -(Vi/(3 Rx)),
   I5 -> (2 Vi)/(9 R), I6 -> 1/9 (2/R + 3/Rx) Vi, Vx -> Vi/3, 
  V3 -> (2 Vi)/3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, this is a *scaled non-inverting amplifier*. It consists of two cascaded devices - *voltage divider* and *non-inverting amplifier*.  This connection makes some sense in the circuit of a simple op-amp differential amplifier where it is used to equalize the gain at both inputs.

If you want to say it in a more intriguing way, two voltage dividers - "straight" (2R and R) and "inverted" (R2, R2 and the op-amp) are cascaded. So, the total ratio is R/(2R + R) x (R2 + R2)/R2 = 2/3... and accordingly, the output voltage is Vin.2/3.

The resistor 3R serves as a load consuming a current IL = Vout/3R... but it does not affect the output voltage.